# Making a new data frame matching with a single data frame to multiple data frames

Tags: r

I am having a data frame of Pincode values (file1.csv).

In another set, I am having multiple files of same set of records(fileset1.csv, fileset2.csv, fileset3.csv(.

I want to pull the matching pincode with the set of rows in multiple files based on the file1.

For example:

I want the pincode and delivery % of all rows of all files a seperate data frame indexed with the pincode file of file1.csv.

Thanks in advance.

file1.csv

```
Pincode        Name        value
110011         sia           N
110012         dia           S
110013         sia           W
```

fileset1.csv

```
Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      56         30          22.26
110044      80         20          35.26
110011      86         30          45.62
```

fileset2.csv

```
Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      106         30           12.26
110044      650         220          55.26
110011      862         130          35.62
```

fileset3.csv

```
Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      567         70          12.26
110044      801         30          25.26
110011      86         80           95.62
```

Expected Output:

```
Pincode          Delivery%
110011           Totalvalue of all (22.26+45.62+12.26+35.62+12.26+95.62)
```

Comment: Yes. I want to merge the fileset into a single file and match with the first pincode file.

Since I am new to R, I need clear guidance to perform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We could place the dataframes in a `list` ('lst'), and then compare the 'Pincode' column in the 'key' dataset ('d1') with each of the `data.frame` 'Pincode' columns in the 'lst' using `%in%`, `subset` the rows of the datasets from the logical index we got from `%in%`.  We can `rbind` the `list` to a single `data.frame`.  Here, I used `rbindlist` from `data.table`.  Then, we can get the `sum` of the 'Delivery%` column grouped by the 'Pincode'.

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) 
              x[x$Pincode %in%d1$Pincode,c('Pincode', 'Delivery%')]))
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst1)[,list(Delivery=sum(`Delivery%`)) , by = Pincode]
#  Pincode Delivery
#1:  110011   223.64
```

I am not sure whether the OP had the read the datasets or not.  For reading the datasets, we can use `read.csv/read.table` or `fread` from `data.table`.   The help pages of `?read.csv` and others have examples to guide if it was not already done.

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(Pincode = 110011:110013, Name = c("sia", "dia", 
"sia"), value = c("N", "S", "W")), .Names = c("Pincode", "Name", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df1 <- read.table(text="Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      56         30          22.26
110044      80         20          35.26
110011      86         30          45.62", 
           sep="", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)




df2 <- read.table(text="Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      106         30           12.26
110044      650         220          55.26
110011      862         130          35.62", 
            sep="", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)


df3 <- read.table(text="Pincode     Orders   Delivery   Delivery%
110011      567         70          12.26
110044      801         30          25.26
110011      86         80           95.62",
            sep="", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```